# Intersection observer with child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to achieve the infinity scroll using intersection observer. I have a list of data which is rendered in child component.

I am attaching the target element to the last of the list element while rendering.

The problem is, after two API calls, it's not triggering since I have a condition in App.js function handleObserver

```
if (this.state.prevY > y) {
```

So after second API call it's not happening the condition is false. So obviously the API call never happen again.

The prevY is getting greater.

How can I resolve this issue, every article shows at the Parent level component. I am trying to implement with Child Component.

```js
App.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from './Child';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    page: 0,
    loading: false,
    prevY: 0,
    isDataAvailable: false
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getUsers(this.state.page)
  }


  getUsers = (page = this.state.page) => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    axios
      .get(`https://api.github.com/users?since=${page}&per_page=100`)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ users: [...this.state.users, ...res.data] });
        this.setState({ loading: false, isDataAvailable: true });
      });
  }

  handleObserver = (entities, observer) => {
    const y = entities[0].boundingClientRect.y;
    if (this.state.prevY > y) {
      const lastUser = this.state.users[this.state.users.length - 1];
      const curPage = lastUser.id;
      this.getUsers(curPage);
      this.setState({ page: curPage });
    }
    this.setState({ prevY: y });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div style={{ minHeight: '800px' }}>
          {this.state.isDataAvailable ? (
            <Child
              handleObserver={this.handleObserver}
              users={this.state.users}
            />
          ) : null}
         
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;



// Child.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const options = {
      root: null,
      threshold: 0,
    };
    this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      this._handleObserver.bind(this),
      options,
    );
    this.observer.observe(this.loadingRef);
  }

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.users !== nextProps.users;
  }

  _handleObserver(entities, observer) {
    this.props.handleObserver(entities)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.users.map(
          (user, index) =>
            (index ===
              this.props.users.length - 1 ? (
                <div>
                  <div ref={loadingRef => (this.loadingRef = loadingRef)} />
                  <li key={user.id}>{user.login}</li>
                </div>
              ) : (
                <li key={user.id}>{user.login}</li>
              )),
        )}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Comment: Going through  your code to learn how you did this.  (Not your question, but noticed, you're missing a .catch() on your axios chain).

Comment: Thanks Mayia, i was trying the implementation, thanks for the quick note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was every time the loadingRef was changing, so we need to point out the ref every time.

```
componentDidUpdate(){
 this.observer.observe(this.loadingRef)
}
```

initially, the loadingRef will be pointed to 99th element later it will 199th element. So we need to update the pointing of loadingRef.

By adding the above code in the child component i was able to resolve the issue.